# Hibernate callback for many-to-many join table operations?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, listener, interceptor

Consider this scenario:

- A Car can have a number of issues
- An issue can be shared by a number of cars

I want to define this relationship using a Many-To-Many mapping with a join table.

And I want a generic column MODIFIED_TS to be maintained automatically on all three tables (yes - I can do it with database triggers - but that is not my ambition).

I have experimented with a variety of hibernate entity listeners and interceptors. They work fine - except for the join table.

Is there anyone out there who knows why callbacks like e.g. preInsert and onSave do not fire when rows are inserted or updated on the join table?

I am using:

- Hibernate 4.3.10.Final
- spring-data-jpa 1.8.1.RELEASE (does it matter?)

Base entity class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_TS")
    private Timestamp modifiedTs;

}
```

Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "LICENSE_PLATE_NUMBER", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String licensePlateNumber;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "CAR_ISSUE", inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID")},
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ISSUE_ID")})
    private Collection<Issue> issues;

}
```

Issue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ISSUE")
public class Issue extends BaseEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "TEXT", nullable = false, length = 2000)
  private String text;

}
```

and CarIssue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR_ISSUE")
public class CarIssue extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ISSUE_ID", nullable = false)
    private long issueId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CAR_ID", nullable = false)
    private long carId;

}
```

My listener:

```
public class MyEntityListener implements PreUpdateEventListener, PreInsertEventListener {

    public boolean setAudit(Object entity, String[] properties, Object[] state) {
        if (entity instanceof BaseEntity) {
            BaseEntity baseEntity = (BaseEntity) entity;
            baseEntity.setModifiedTs(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

            List<String> propertiesList = Arrays.asList(properties);
            state[propertiesList.indexOf("modifiedTs")] = baseEntity.getModifiedTs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
        return setAudit(event.getEntity(), event.getPersister().getPropertyNames(), event.getState());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
        return setAudit(event.getEntity(), event.getPersister().getPropertyNames(), event.getState());
    }

}
```

and finally this piece of code:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setLicensePlateNumber("ABC123");
ArrayList<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<>();
Issue issue = new Issue();
issue.setDescription("Two wheels missing");
issues.add(issue);
car.setIssues(issues);
carRepo.save(car);
```

This works fine - I get a row in all three tables - but MODIFIED_TS only gets populated for CAR and ISSUE.

Any help is greatly appreciated:-)